# Google App Engine populating datastore entries

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to populate my datastore with some values. What is the best way to do this ?
This is my code -

```
for n in range(seqlen):
  for m in range(n+1):
    for l in range(m+1):
      temp = [-BIGINT for k in range(m-l+1)]
      obj = DbEntity4D(key_name=str(n)+','+str(m) +','+ str(l))
      obj.value = temp
      obj.put()
```

or is this one better ?

```
for n in range(seqlen):
  for m in range(n+1):
    for l in range(m+1):
      temp = [-BIGINT for k in range(m-l+1)]
      obj[i] = DbEntity4D(key_name=str(n)+','+str(m) +','+ str(l))
      obj[i].value = temp
      i = i+1

    db.put(obj)
```

Or is there any other better way ?

seqlen can be 1 to 1000. It may not be able to finish this whole process in 10 mins but I can continue from where I left previously in my next task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batching datastore puts will save a significant amount of time by eliminating round-trips to the datastore.

It looks like you're trying to do this with your latter block of code (saving `m` entities at a time).  In the case where `seqlen` is 1000, you'll write up to 1000 entities at a time.  However, the number entities written at once varies since your innermost for loop varies in how many entities it produces.  It might be faster still if you wait to save to the database until you've collected `n` (some large number) of `DbEntity4D` entities, and then save them (rather than always saving them immediately after your innermost loop).  Of course, this might complicate the logic which allows the next task to resume adding creating these entities where a previous task left off.

Comment: agreed. i'd also suggest using remote_api instead of trying to do this in a single request or task, since a remote_api script running outside of app engine can run for as long as you want.